# Меню со скошенными углами

Tags: javascript, css, html5, css3, вёрстка

Есть меню вида [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пробовал сделать скошенные края через 
`li:nth-child(2n):after`
`li:nth-child(2n):before`
вставлять для четных `li`-шек треугольники (через абсолютное позиционирование)
и таким же образом для нечетных… но любое изменение размера окна и все плывет 
я так понимаю не лучший способ. Пробовал через `perspective` и `tranform: rotateX()` но как тогда быть с 1-м последним элементом у которых нет скоса…
Подскажите как можно такую менюху реализовать…

вот то что пробовал

```
ul {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 0px;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
        padding-left: 0px;
        li{
           padding: 20px 100px 30px 120px;
           text-align: center;
           background-color: #fff;
           flex: 1 1 100px;
           margin-left: 50px;
           box-shadow: 4px -4px 45px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

           &:nth-child(2n):after{
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 0px;
                            border-bottom: 86px solid #fff;
                            border-right: 30px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0px;
                            content: "";
                            left: 428px;
                     }

                     &:nth-child(2n):before{
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 100%;
                            border-bottom: 89px solid #fff;
                            border-left: 35px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
                            position: absolute;
                            bottom: 0px;
                            content: "";
                            left: -34px;
                     }


                     &:nth-child(odd):after{
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 0px;
                            border-top: 90px solid #fff;
                            border-right: 35px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0px;
                            content: "";
                            left: 428px;
                     }

                      &:nth-child(odd):before{
                            width: 0px;
                            height: 0px;
                            border-top: 90px solid #fff;
                            border-left: 32px solid rgba(255, 0, 0, 0);
                            position: absolute;
                            top: 0px;
                            content: "";
                            left: 929px;
                     }
       }
```

html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="">link<br><span>Boldlink</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="">link<br><span>Boldlin</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="">link<br><span>Boldlin</span></a></li>
    <li><a href="">link<br><span>Boldlink</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

так я выставил треугольники под определенную ширину экрана на свои места, но тут я не смог исключить 1-й и последний элемент корректно (чтобы у них не отображались треугольники), ну и после малейшего ресайза все треугольники уползают кто куда…

Comment: Можете добавить в вопрос свой вариант решения? Интересно увидеть, что и почему плывет при изменении размеров окна.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Добавил вот такую разметку. Её плюсы это гибкость и сопровождаемость. Если надо менять угол треугольника, то меняйте `skew` и `width` для псевдоэлементов.

#### Решение через псевдоэлементы

Задаём для каждого нечётного элемента треугольник, а для чётного — перевёрнутый треугольник. Прячем для первого и последнего ребёнка соответствующие псевдоэлементы.

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu__item {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu__item + .menu__item {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.menu__item:before,
.menu__item:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu__item:before {
  left: -50px;
}

.menu__item:nth-child(odd):before {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) translateX(50%);
}

.menu__item:nth-child(even):before {
  transform: skewX(30deg) translateX(50%);  
}

/* Прячем первый псеводоэлемент */
.menu__item:first-child:before {
  display: none;
}

.menu__item:after {
  right: 0;
}

.menu__item:nth-child(odd):after {
    transform: skewX(30deg) translateX(50%);
}

.menu__item:nth-child(even):after {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) translateX(50%);  
}

/* Прячем последний псеводоэлемент */
.menu__item:last-child:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="menu__item">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="menu__item">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="menu__item">
    Link
  </div>
</div>
```

#### Решение через классы

Решение без псевдоселекторов. Указываем явно для элементов треугольники (которые образуют скошенные края) через классы `.menu__item--triangle-before`,
`.menu__item--reversed-triangle-before`,
`.menu__item--triangle-after`,
`.menu__item--reversed-triangle-after`. Удобно тогда, когда нет чёткой последовательности для элементов меню или часть прячется, или меняется порядок (свойство CSS `order`) и т.д. То есть данное решение более мощное, чем решение с псевдоселекторами, но требует написания большего количества кода.

```css
.menu {
  display: flex;
}

.menu__item {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.menu__item + .menu__item {
  margin-left: 60px;
}

.menu__item--triangle-before:before,
.menu__item--reversed-triangle-before:before,
.menu__item--triangle-after:after,
.menu__item--reversed-triangle-after:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  background-color: orange;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.menu__item--triangle-before:before,
.menu__item--reversed-triangle-before:before {
  left: -50px;
}

.menu__item--triangle-before:before {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) translateX(50%);
}

.menu__item--reversed-triangle-before:before {
  transform: skewX(30deg) translateX(50%);  
}

.menu__item--triangle-after:after,
.menu__item--reversed-triangle-after:after {
  right: 0;
}

.menu__item--triangle-after:after {
    transform: skewX(30deg) translateX(50%);
}

.menu__item--reversed-triangle-after:after {
  transform: skewX(-30deg) translateX(50%);  
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--triangle-after">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--reversed-triangle-before menu__item--reversed-triangle-after">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--triangle-before menu__item--triangle-after">
    Link
  </div>
  <div class="menu__item menu__item--reversed-triangle-before">
    Link
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Круто! Но у меня не отображаются transform: skew(30deg) translateX(50%); то есть как раз скосов у меня не видно  может ли на это влиять то что у меня весь блок   "menu" обернут в блок с классом на котором висит background... при отключении его скосы все равно не на месте...

Comment: В смысле не отображается? Какой браузер? В чём именно ваша проблема?

Comment: в Chrome при добавлении просто прямоугольники

Comment: Сейчас исправил значение. При добавлении нового элемента?

Comment: да нет тут в этом коде... ну я  разберусь в коде и допилю под себя...
Спасибо огромное за помощь!

Comment: Сейчас вам ещё один способ добавлю

Comment: Добавил, смотрите. Может вам больше подойдёт.

Comment: Вообще красавчик :)

Comment: Это  реально хорошая реализация спасибо!. Но раз уже на то пошло то в таком случае как организовать общую тень от блока... ведь составляющие все отдельно и тень будет делиться?

Comment: @FastTI с тенью ничего сложного: добавьте к примеру для `.menu__item { box-shadow: 0 5px #000; }` и для `.menu__item:before, .menu__item:after { box-shadow: 5px 5px #000; }`